# Utilizar o Rand e atribuir aleatóriamente em todas as colunas

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Tenho esta tabela (centrodb.InfoColaboradores) que tem os ids de todas as outras tabelas que faço o `join` na base de dados com estes dados:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tenho esta query:**

```
SELECT B.NomeColaborador, 
   C.Ala,
   D.Grupo,
   E.Turno

FROM centrodb.RelacaoColab AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.InfoColaboradores AS B

ON B.Id = A.IdColab LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.TiposAlas AS C

ON C.Id = A.IdAla LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.TiposGrupos AS D

ON D.Id = A.IdGrup LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.H_Turno AS E

ON E.Id = A.IdTurn

WHERE E.Turno = 'M' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8
```

Como faço para não aparecerem repetidas estas situações ao gerar os 8 funcionários dos 11 que tenho na tabela da base de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Para que os nomes não se repitam basta colocar no final da query antes do `order`:

```
GROUP BY B.NomeColaborador
```

a questão das outras informações duplicadas, creio que seja pelo uso dos

```
left joins
```

Veja como funciona o left join:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja ele vai trazer as informações da tabela da esquerda caso não seja igual.
Tente usar apenas `inner join`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

lugar aonde peguei as imagens [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-sql-multiple-tables/)

**Como fica sua query?**

```
SELECT B.NomeColaborador, 
   C.Ala,
   D.Grupo,
   E.Turno

FROM centrodb.RelacaoColab AS A JOIN centrodb.InfoColaboradores AS B

ON B.Id = A.IdColab JOIN centrodb.TiposAlas AS C

ON C.Id = A.IdAla JOIN centrodb.TiposGrupos AS D

ON D.Id = A.IdGrup JOIN centrodb.H_Turno AS E

ON E.Id = A.IdTurn

WHERE E.Turno = 'M' GROUP BY B.NomeColaborador ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Mas se não colocar os outros nomes das colunas que se encontram no `SELECT` dá erro e ao colocar repete os nomes dos colaboradores, das alas e do grupo